# Selecting text in bash with shift+arrow keys

Tags: linux, bash, opensuse

I just installed OpenSuse on my laptop and everything is fine, except in the bash shell I can't use 
 shift + left/right arrow keys to select text. 
How do I turn this feature on?

Comment: I did some research and the consensus is that bash doesn't support this.

Comment: this also occurs on `ubuntu 20 gnome` and `manjaro 21 xfce`